# c++ fstream regarding reading file on certain lines of .txt files

Tags: c++

So I am very new to c++ and on an assignment I have for school I am making a program that uses fstream to put in userIds and passwords into a text file and I am not sure why this will not work when trying to confirm that the username and pass are correct

```
int login()
{
    fstream accountFile2;
    bool confirm;
    string userID;
    string accountPass;
    string IDConfirm;
    string PassConfirm;
    accountFile2.open("accountfile.txt",ios::in | ios::out);

    cout<<"Login!\n Enter your User ID: "<<endl;
    cin>>userID;
    cout<<"Please enter your account's password\n";
    cin>>accountPass;

    accountFile>>IDConfirm;
    accountFile>>PassConfirm;
    accountFile2.close();

    if((userID == IDConfirm) && (accountPass == PassConfirm))
    {
        confirm = 1;
        cout<<"success";
    }
    else
    {
        confirm =0;
        cout<<"invalid id/pass";
    }

    return confirm;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what _"does not work"_ actually means - what error do you get or what is the difference between the desired and observed outcome? And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I think there in typo
`accountFile>>IDConfirm;
  accountFile>>PassConfirm;`
The file opened by you is accountFile2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `accountFile` and `accountFile2` is a typo, it works for me ([and the compiler](http://goo.gl/8hsZya)).

Double check that the file exists and contains right data. Also beware, that `std::cin >> variable` for variable of type `std::string` will read only one word (will stop reading when it finds whitespace). If you want to read whole line, use `std::getline(std::cin, variable)` instead.